# Generate a Mock object with a Method which raises an event

Tags: rhino-mocks, vb.net-2010

I am working on a VB.NET project which requires the extensive used of Unit Tests but am having problems mocking on of the classes.

Here is a breakdown of the issue:

- Using NUnit and Rhino Mock 3.6
- VS2010 & VB.NET
- I have an interface which contains a number of methods and an Event.
- The class which implements that Interface raises the event when one of the methods is called.

When I mock the object in my tests I can stub methods and create/assert expectations on the methods with no problems.

How do I configure the mock object so that when a method is called the event is raised so that I can assert that is was raised?

I have found numerous posts using C# which suggest code like this

```
mockObject.MyEvent += null...
```

When I try this 'MyEvent' does not appear in Intellisense.

I'm obviously not configuring my test/mock correctly but with so few VB.NET examples out there I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: "configure the mock object so that when a method is called the event is raised so that I can assert that is was raised" - it sound like you are going to test the mock. Can you explain more detailed what exactly you are going to test? Code examples would also be helpful here.

Comment: I think you may be right - the code I'm trying to add tests for (not proper TDD I know) is not well structured so its been a bit confusing to work out what I actually need to mock out and what I need to test. Looks like I may have a refactoring exercise on my hands before I can hope to add some meaningful tests.

Comment: Could you post your code and show in it what you try to achieve.

Comment: @Marwijn: Can't post the actual code really but will try to get a dummy sample sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my lack of VB syntax; I'm a C# guy. Also, I think you should be congratulated for writing tests at all, regardless of test first or test last.

I think your code needs refactoring. It sounds like you have an interface that requires implementations to contain an event, and then another class (which you're testing) depends on this interface. The code under test then executes the event when certain things happen.

The question in my mind is, "Why is it a publically exposed `event`?" Why not just a method that implementations can define? I suppose the `event` could have multiple `delegate`s being added to it dynamically somewhere, but if that's something you **really** need, then the implementation should figure out how that works. You could replace the `event` with a pair of methods: `HandleEvent([event parameters])` and `AddEventListener(TheDelegateType listener)`. I think the meaning and usage of those should be obvious enough. If the implementation wants to use `event`s internally, it can, but I feel like that's an implementation detail that users of the interface should not care about. All they should care about is adding their listener and that all the listeners get called. Then you can just assert that `HandleEvent` or `AddEventListener` were called. This is probably the simplest way to make this more testable.

If you really need to keep the `event`, then see [here](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%20Mocking%20Delegates.ashx) for information on mocking `delegate`s. My advice would be to mock a `delegate`, add it to the event during set up, and then assert it was called. [This](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Events.ashx) might also be useful if you need to test that things are added to the event.

Also, I wouldn't rely on Intellisense too much. Mocking is done via some crafty IL code, I believe. I wouldn't count on Intellisense to keep up with members of its objects, especially when you start getting beyond normal methods.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacl - and you're absolutely right, the code needs refactoring. At the moment it is pretty much all over the place due to the inclusion of code which was intended as a proof of concept. Probably would have been better to junk it and start again.
The issue is the use of a 3rd party component which talks to a PLC. We have wrapped this to allow us to use an interface and IoC but it is the abstraction of this component which is causing my headache. I'm sure I need to mock the wrapper to allow us to test effectively but I'm getting tied up in the implementation/configuration

Comment: You may find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9FOchgTtLM) interesting. The guy said something that surprised me: don't mock the edges of your code; that duplicates a third party's specifications. In a recent project, my team decided let our integration tests cover most of the code that touched other libraries. I'm not sure how favorably that's viewed, but it's worked out pretty well for us so far. I think it's important to consider you tests from a business perspective, too. Try to write tests that will save you time/effort in the long run or they're not very valuable.

Comment: @DilbertDave In other words, it's just as import to identify when you shouldn't test as when you should (or alternatively, **how** you should test).